# Understanding scrollr parallax pause code

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I was just trying to use scrollr on one of my sites. This is my first time using this plugin. I saw [this example](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/pausing.html).

Basically I am interested in how to pause a div and show an animation.

So the html for the paused div is as follows:

```html
<div data-0="transform:translate(0,100%);" data-100p="transform:translate(0,0%)" data-_box-100p="" data-_box-200p="transform:translate(0,-100%)">
        <div class="box" data-100p="width:0%;" data-_box-100p="width:100%"></div>
</div>
```

Now I am not quite understanding the usage of `data-_box-100p="" data-_box-200p="transform:translate(0,-100%)"`.

And the JavaScript used to initialize this plugin here:

```js
skrollr.init({
        constants: {
            //fill the box for a "duration" of 150% of the viewport (pause for 150%)
            //adjust for shorter/longer pause
            box: '150p'
        }
    });
```

Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr?tab=readme-ov-file#working-with-constants) the following line initializes a constant variable named `box` with the value `150p`:

```js
skrollr.init({
  constants: {
    box: '150p'
  }
});
```

Once again, the [documentation](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr?tab=readme-ov-file#percentage-offsets) mentions that `150p` is an offset value set to reflect the **percentage of the viewport**.

Given that the variable `box` has the value `150p` we can understand the following line:

`data-_box-100p="" data-_box-200p="transform:translate(0,-100%)"`

...like this:

`data-150p-100p="" data-150p-200p="transform:translate(0,-100%)"`

Which boils down to this, after the calculations (subtracting `100p` and `200p`):

`data-50p="" data--50p="transform:translate(0,-100%)"`

The plugin will replace `_box` *(the variable must be prefixed with the _ character. Once again, check the [docs](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr?tab=readme-ov-file#working-with-constants) for the variable syntax.)* with the associated value (150p) and do the calculations.

Basically, this is all about the good old advice: RTFM.